# Access Data Management issue

Tags: sorting, ms-access

I am facing problem in Data Management in MS Access.I have two coloumn i.e sku and child sku.Each parent sku have child sku in front and same child sku exist in parent column on some other **sequence/Place**.What i require is to display child sku value along with parent sku.Present data is given below.

```
Parent SKU    Child Sku
vou1          adf1 
vou2          adf2
vou3          adf3
tu1
tu2
tu3
adf1
adf2
adf3
```

What i require is to display data in below **mentioned format**

```
Parent SKU    Child Sku
vou1          adf1 
vou2          adf2
vou3          adf3
adf1
adf2
adf3
tu1
tu2
tu3
```

If possible please help to resolve this data Sort/Management issue--thanks.

Comment: Can you please re-format your question? See here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are getting at.  You want to link the `Child Sku` record to the `Parent Sku` record so you can access the data from both.  You can do a self join to accomplish this:

```
SELECT ct.*, pt.*
FROM MyTable pt
INNER JOIN MyTable ct ON ct.[Child Sku] = pt.[Parent Sku]
```

Then change `ct.*` and  `pt.*` to the actual fields you want.

Comment: Thanks for your response.What i require is to link parent and child and display child record below each parent.If possible please change query so that below each parent child record should be displayed.